# Update value of column in Form Library using CSOM

Tags: infopath, client-object-model, sharepoint-addin

I want to update the value of a promoted field from infopath form by csom code. I have written the following code but it does not seem to work. Please guide to know what is incorrect.

```
   function UpdateCategory(val)
      {
        context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var web = context.get_web();
         context.load(web);
         var currentlibid = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList();
         alert('currentlibid' + currentlibid);
         var currentLib = web.get_lists().getById(currentlibid);
         var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
         for(var i in selectedItems)
          {
            currentItem = currentLib.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id);
            alert('currentItem: ' + currentItem);
            context.load(currentItem);
            alert('loadd :' + context.load(currentItem));
            if(currentItem != null) {
              currentItem.set_item('Form Approval', val);
              currentItem.update();
            }
            context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryFailed);
          }//           

      UpdateCategory('0'); //function call
```

I get the following error : Column 'Form Approval' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user.  /Leave Application Form

Please help.

Comment: Looks like you are not using the internal name of the column! The internal names does not have spaces in the name.

Comment: I have also tried with the internal name of the column, one that is displayed in browser's address bar, but it gives the same error.